# D&D 5e Variant Human +1 Skill

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, skills, human

In D&D 5e, variant humans receive an additional skill upon creation. Does this skill have to  belong to the same class as the character or can it be from any class? For example, if I made a variant human barbarian could I choose the skill acrobatics? Or, would it have to be an additional one from the barbarian skill list?

Comment: Hi, generally there is no need to post the same question a second time. Your original question would have been re-opened for answers when it met the community guidelines. However, since you have already gone ahead and done it I have posted my answer here, just keep that in mind for any future questions.

Comment: @smbailey We really shouldn't be letting these go with a workaround. I've closed and recommend you post an answer to the original as well.

Answer (score 2):

The [Variant Human](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/human#VariantHuman) optional rule includes the following text (*Player's Handbook* pg. 31):

> ***Skills.*** You gain proficiency in one skill of your choice.

It is a skill of your choice, it can be any skill from the skills list regardless of what you have chosen for your class.